# Seaborn Not Working from Script in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Python 2.7.12

matplotlib 1.5.1

Seaborn 0.8.0

Ubuntu 16.04, with the pip package manager.

I have tried running the codes in seaborn gallery.

They simply do not work when I run a script from terminal. They just say 
"seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid object at 0x7fdfa554c1d0". Matplotlib works though.

Seaborn does work, however, from the jupyter notebook in my browser. But even then, the plots are really bland and simple, not many interactive customisation options. Nothing like the attractive, feature rich and aesthetically pleasing things you see on tutorials, or the gallery.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: "really bland and simple" is not clear. You would need to link to an example and show what you get in comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a plot, you need to call

```
plt.show()
```

where `plt` is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.